# Selfhosting wcf console prints data

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm having the following console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SampleServiceNamespace.SampleService)))
        {
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Service up and running at:");
            foreach (var ea in host.Description.Endpoints)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ea.Address);
            }

            //

            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }
    }
```

And the wcf library implements the following:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
Person aPerson = new Person();
    public string GreetMe(Person person)
    {
        return string.Format("Greetings from Sample service Mr. {0}", person.Name);

    }

    public void setPersonName(string aName) //Output this aPerson.Name to the screen
    {
        aPerson.Name = aName;
    }
```

The interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISampleService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GreetMe(Person person);
    [OperationContract]
    void setPersonName(string aName);
}

[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to print to the screen the data. For example every time I send from the client a string for name i want to output this on the screen.

Comment: Did you try to do it in SampleService? Of course if you want a more _general_ solution you may consider (carefully) also AOP.

Comment: Do what? Set the name? What is AOP?

Comment: Well, what should work is that you simply call Console.WriteLine(string) from your method, that handles the request from client. Since you are self hosting the service as a ConsoleApplication, there should be no issue with it. Also, if you want for example message box, you can use WinForms as well (be sure to add reference)

Comment: Perhaps i could create an object of type Person and access it from the wcf library? is there a way to avoid circular reference error?

Comment: That depends on where and what you would like to print to the screen. You said for example the string (name) that is being sent from client - in such case, you can put `Console.WriteLine(aName);` into your `setPersonName(string aName)` method, that is being called by client

Comment: I can access the Program class from my wcf library? are you sure? Because the opposite is available cause of the reference.

Comment: For me, it is working. I can not access the Program class directly, but I can pass messages to console. See this project for example: http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/a-truely-simple-example-to-get-started-with-wcf  and the part "Service implementation", where the message is being printed as well (before returning the string).